# Android: equalsIgnoreCase is not giving proper output

Tags: java, android

i need help with android code. i am using CITIES ( a String array) to compare with the input text.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent forwardIntent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
        AutoCompleteTextView inputSource = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.source_city);

        String source_city = inputSource.getText().toString();
        if(source_city.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
        {
            Toast.makeText(SourceActivity.this, "Enter the name of city ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            for(String city: CITIES){
                if(city.equalsIgnoreCase(source_city)){
                    forwardIntent.putExtra("source_city", source_city);
                    SourceActivity.this.startActivity(forwardIntent);
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SourceActivity.this, "We don't have service for above mentioned city" + source_city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }

            }}
    }
```

The problem is that in any case i am getting the output as We don't have service for above mentioned cityCITY Name; the Toast message of the last else part. Can anyone help to rectify the problem. 
Thnx in advance..!!

Comment: Have you tried to print/toast "city" and see you are getting valid value?

Comment: Yeah i am getting a value. Lets say i am passing Mumbai as my input. Then on Button Click i get a Toast saying We don't have service for above mentioned city Mumbai. But i have included Mumbai in my CITIES  String array.

Comment: If source_city and city both showing as "Mumbai", then I would say to city.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(source_city) and see. May be some white spaces causing issue?

Comment: Figured it out. it was improper design of if-else statements.